# my button in very simply web site won't log in console

Tags: javascript, html

i create a very simple website with javascript and html and all i want to do is log input value to the console and my console is printing something and immediately delete it
html:

```js
const alertFunction = () => {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("input"))
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <title>Button With Alert</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Please type your name" class="input" type="text">
    <br />
    <button class="button" onclick="alertFunction()">Alert Your Name</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have few issues in you code:

Since the default type of *button* is *submit*, on clicking it from submission is happening. Thus everything disappears. To prevent the form submission you can either use `event.preventDefault()` inside the event handler function ***or*** specify the `type="button"` in the element.

[`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) ***returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names***. You have to use proper *index* to get the specific element. Finally get the value from the input using *value* property.

```js
const alertFunction = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
        <title>Button With Alert</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input placeholder="Please type your name" class="input" type="text">
            <br />
            <button type="button" class="button" onclick="alertFunction()">Alert Your Name</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `NodeList object`. Access the element and get value using `.value`.
Also use `input type=button` instead of button. Because button click will perform submit event which is not required

Refer- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

```js
const alertFunction = function() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Please type your name" class="input" type="text">
    <br />
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="alertFunction()" value="Alert Your Name">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default event of form submit

```js
const alertFunction = (event) => {
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <title>Button With Alert</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Please type your name" class="input" type="text">
    <br />
    <button class="button" onclick="alertFunction(event)">Alert Your Name</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```